# Using Adal JS in an Angular JS App for Office 365

Tags: angularjs, office365, adal

I am creating a basic html site that is using Angular JS and Adal Js to connect to Office 365. Below are the issues faced -

- **The page is not redirecting for login purpose**.
- **Getting "unexpected token" and "[$injector:modulerr]" error in the
  browser console.**

I have configured application in Azure AD with following details -

- SIGN-ON URL : http://localhost: port number/
- APP ID URI : https:// tenant name/ThomasO365
- REPLY URL : http://localhost: port number/

  Exchange and SharePoint permission has been provided to the application.

**Application Code**

```js
var o365CorsApp = angular.module("o365CorsApp", ['ngRoute', 'AdalAngular']) // loading the ADAL JS Angular module


o365CorsApp.config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', 'adalAuthenticationServiceProvider',

  function($routeProvider, $httpProvider, adalProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        controller: 'HomeController',
        templateUrl: 'index.html',
        requireADLogin: true
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });

    var adalConfig = {
      tenant: '<tentant name>',
      clientId: '<client id>',
      extraQueryParameter: 'nux=1',
      endpoints: {
        "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0": "https://outlook.office365.com/"
      }
    };

    adalProvider.init(adalConfig, $httpProvider);

  }
]);



o365CorsApp.factory('o365CorsFactory', ['$http',
  function($http) {
    var factory = {};

    factory.getContacts = function() {

      return $http.get('https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/contacts')

    }

    return factory;
  }
]);




o365CorsApp.controller("HomeController", function($scope, $q, o365CorsFactory) {

  o365CorsFactory.getContacts().then(function(response) {
    $scope.contacts = response.data.value;
  });


});
```

```html
<html ng-app="o365CorsApp">

<head>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="adal-angular.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="adal.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="HomeController">{{contacts.Email}}
  <br/>
  <p></p>

</body>

</html>
```

I am referencing [this](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/31064.office-365-part-2-adal-js.aspx) article. I am using Brackets instead of Visual Studio.

Note-

- Tenant and Client ID are correct.
- Oauth2AllowImplicitFlow is set to true in manifest file.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going through that article and finding some omissions. Here's some issues I found (don't know if they're causing your error though):

1. Cut and paste of the code introduces extra spaces in the URL's in app.js. Make sure there are no trailing spaces or spaces between the `?` and the rest of the URLs.
2. The code in app.js has values for `tenant` and `clientId` that are obviously for the author, and they never tell you how to replace those with valid values for your app. You can get the correct `clientId` from the Azure Management Portal. `tenant` is a bit trickier to get the GUID, but luckily you can just put your domain name there (like `contoso.onmicrosoft.com`).

Other things to check:

- Make sure that you enabled the implicit OAuth2 flow by downloading the manifest, setting `oauth2AllowImplicitFlow` to `true`, and reuploading (per the article).
- Make sure you are signing into the app using an account that is in the same domain as the one you specify in the `tenant` property.
- Try changing your reply URL to remove `index.html`. That may be messing with the ADAL libraries token parser.

Comment: Hi Jason, Thanks for the response. I will check again by removing the index.html. Edited my question for better clarification.